# IDP Initiated SSO Implementation in existing App

Tags: java, spring, single-sign-on

I have an existing application and all of a sudden i have been given a task to implement IDP initiated SSO. there is a URL to IDP clicking on it asks me to login with IDP provided credentials, after success login the route moves to our application and than my task start to identify the user and give the proper access. I have the certificate provided from our IDP. How can i achieve this? My application is a Spring MVC Java Application.I am using JBOSS AS 7. I havent done a similar thing before. Can anyone please give a step by step clear picture on this? I saw the Spring SAML extension which i couldnt understand properly to get it integrate with my existing app.  Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the Quick Start Guide? http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html You should probably download the SAML extension and take a look at the example they provide.

Comment: I couldnt understand it clearly how to integrate it in my application.

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you install the SAML extension?  Essentially and IDP replaces your login screen with theirs, and provides a set of services for you to call.

Comment: Yes I did it, now the IDP goes to my application. But this Spring SAML seems to be more of a SP Initiated rather than IDP initiated. How i am going to authorize at Application level using my certificates etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IdP-Initiated SSO**

[IdP-Initiated SSO with POST Binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgjtF.png)

1. If the user does not have a valid local security context at the IdP, at some point the user will be challenged to supply their credentials to the IdP site, idp.example.org.
2. The user provides valid credentials and a local logon security context is created for the user at the IdP.
3. The user selects a menu option or link on the IdP to request access to an SP web site, sp.example.com. This causes the IdP's Single Sign-On Service to be called.
4. The Single Sign-On Service builds a SAML assertion representing the user's logon security context. Since a POST binding is going to be used, the assertion is digitally signed before it is placed within a SAML  message. The  message is then placed within an HTML FORM as a hidden form control named SAMLResponse. (If the convention for identifying a specific application resource at the SP is supported at the IdP and SP, the resource URL at the SP is also encoded into the form using a hidden form control named RelayState.) The Single Sign-On Service sends the HTML form back to the browser in the HTTP response. For ease-of-use purposes, the HTML FORM typically will contain script code that will automatically post the form to the destination site.
5. The browser, due either to a user action or execution of an “auto-submit” script, issues an HTTP POST request to send the form to the SP's Assertion Consumer Service. The service provider's Assertion Consumer Service obtains the  message from the HTML FORM for processing. The digital signature on the SAML assertion must first be validated and then the assertion contents are processed in order to create a local logon security context for the user at the SP. Once this completes, the SP retrieves the RelayState data (if any) to determine the desired application resource URL and sends an HTTP redirect response to the browser directing it to access the requested resource (not shown).
6. An access check is made to establish whether the user has the correct authorization to access the resource. If the access check passes, the resource is then returned to the browser.

See [saml-tech-overview-2.0](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/27819/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.pdf)

So if you are implementing the SP, you have to follow the steps 5 and 6 otherwise 1 - 4.

For the implementation you could use **OpenSaml** if you do not get it working with the Spring SAML extension.